# Is there any open source/freeware TSO/ISP clone for PC?

Tags: tso

Free as in beer. I can live without the source code.

About 10 years ago I saw a commercial product. Is there anything free now?

I found [Gispf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gispf/) on SourceForge, but there are no downloads. Otherwise, I can't find a thing.

---

Edit: I'd prefer something approaching the whole system, but could manage to live with the editor

---

Edit" TSO is "the old Time-Sharing Option on IBM mainframes"

Comment: Would you like to explain what you're looking for?  The only thing I'm coming up with for TSO is the old Time-Sharing Option on IBM mainframes, and I don't know what the "while system" is.

Comment: Yes, that TSO   ("while" was a typo for "Whole". Sorry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have tried anything listed on [Dave's SPF Editor page](http://www.planetmvs.com/spfeditor/)